# How can I declare this anonymous class abstract?

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

While working on some code, I encountered some problem related to this piece of code:

```
public class Test {
    final int f = 0;

    void method() {
        new AbstractClass() {

            @Override
            public void methodInner() {

            }
        };
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractClass {
        int f;

        public abstract void methodInner();

    }
}
```

Now, while doing some modifications in the code, I did not override the abstract method in the abstract class.

```
public class Test {
    final int f = 0;

    void method() {
        new AbstractClass() {
        };
    }

    public static abstract class AbstractClass {
        int f;

        public abstract void methodInner();

    }
}
```

Now I was sure that this will give an error as I have not overridden the method. The error it gave:

> java: <anonymous Test$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method methodInner() in Test.AbstractClass

Now I tried to make `<anonymous Test$1>` abstract, but I couldn't do it. Is there a way to make this anonymous inner class abstract?

Comment: No. Your anonymous class is used to create an instance. You can't directly instantiate an abstract class. That is what makes it abstract.

Comment: @khelwood Just wanted to be sure, thanks.

Comment: You cannot make an anonymous class abstract. It would make little sense if you could because you cannot extend anonymous classes and can not instantiate abstract classes so an abstract anonymous class is by definition unusable.

Comment: Anonymous classes can't be abstract as they are instantiated on spot (hence the `new Something(){...}`). Abstract classes are not "ready" for instantiation, that's what being abstract means.

Comment: @khelwood Then why does the error says you to declare it abstract or...

Comment: Because it did not even reach the instantiation part. It just sees that the class is incomplete, so it either has to be completed or marked abstract. But the latter is not possible here and now simply because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah got it thanks..